# Geolocation of Google Compute Engine Servers?

Tags: geolocation, google-compute-engine

When creating a new instance, GCE cloud allows choosing among three regions: West Europe, Central US and Asia.

I'd like to know exactly where the instance is allocated, e.g., know the precise coordinates.

GeoLocation databases point all GCE-allocated IP addresses to Mountain View, CA (Google HQ). Is there a way to find out the correct exact location?

Comment: Google should publish the network allocation by data center. We have seen Microsoft and Amazon published it for their clients.

Comment: @MichaelC. they definitely should, but it seems they don't, and leave us guessing. I wonder why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on ping times and traceroutes, [I've made some educated guesses](https://blog.serverdensity.com/5-things-probably-dont-know-google-cloud/):

- US Central 1: [Oklahoma](https://www.google.com/about/datacenters/inside/locations/mayes-county/)
- Europe West 1: [Ireland](https://www.google.com/about/datacenters/inside/locations/dublin/)
- Asia East 1: [Changhua County, Taiwan](https://www.google.com/about/datacenters/inside/locations/changhua-county/)

Comment: Oklahoma is misspelled. I would change it but Stack Overflow has a dense policy against minor edits.

Comment: Google now publishes the locations at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/regions-zones#available

Answer (score 5):

This page shows the physical locations of Google's datacenters: http://www.google.com/about/datacenters/inside/locations/index.html

But no precise information on which datacenter houses which GCE Zone.

Answer (score 2):

These days, Google is giving a little more information, on this page:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/

```
Region                  Zones           Location
asia-east1              a, b, c         Changhua County, Taiwan
asia-northeast1         a, b, c         Tokyo, Japan
asia-south1             a, b, c         Mumbai, India
asia-southeast1         a, b, c         Jurong West, Singapore
australia-southeast1    a, b, c         Sydney, Australia
europe-north1           a, b, c         Hamina, Finland
europe-west1            b, c, d         St. Ghislain, Belgium
europe-west2            a, b, c         London, England, UK
europe-west3            a, b, c         Frankfurt, Germany
europe-west4            a, b, c         Eemshaven, Netherlands
northamerica-northeast1 a, b, c         Montréal, Québec, Canada
southamerica-east1      a, b, c         São Paulo, Brazil
us-central1             a, b, c, f      Council Bluffs, Iowa, USA
us-east1                b, c, d         Moncks Corner, South Carolina, USA
us-east4                a, b, c         Ashburn, Northern Virginia, USA
us-west1                a, b, c         The Dalles, Oregon, USA
us-west2                a, b, c         Los Angeles, California, USA
```

They give the city, which is hopefully close enough. Now just get latitude / longitude from Google Maps or something for each city.